# Should I concatenate my dependencies on my Javascript library?

Tags: javascript, performance, d3.js

I'm working on a JS library that relies heavily on D3 (and to some extent, lodash). I've modularized it, have `bower_components` for the external library dependencies and `node` and `gulp` for the build/concatenation/uglifying process. So I'm covered from the development standpoint (no need for require.js).

However, in order to let other people use my library, they *need* to have both d3 and loadash loaded. I don't want to bloat their loading but at the same time I want to make things easy for everyone. Should I just concatenate my dependencies along with my `.min.js` and have that be a release? What are the best practices?

BTW, my current versions of lodash and d3 clock in at 52k and 148k respectively. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I seems interesting to embed dependencies in your own library to offer customers an easier way to integrate your component, but think about that:

- They may use another component requiring a more up-to-date D3 (you embedded)
- For performance reason at load time, your customer may want to use D3 (or other embedded libraries) using the official CDN (better access and downloading time)
- You will have to carry about updating your component each time one of your dependency is fixed.

For other more reason you could find by yourself, it is not a good practice to embed dependencies inside your component unless you plan to manage a full support of it.